# Writing Inputstream to File as png on Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream, fileoutputstream

Can you take an inputStream from a png file encrypt and send out as an encrypted stream and save it as a png picture file?

After encryption I want to decrypt the file and view it, but am not able to see the photo from the decrypted stream.

When I save an OutputStream I am not able to view the file, encrypted or decrypted. I'm not throwing any exceptions I am just not able to see the photo after decrypting an encrypted version.

My attempt do decrypt the file looks like this.

```
public void testDecryptionOfPhoto() throws Exception{
    File file = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "encryptedTest.png");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStream decryptedPhoto = decryption.decryptInputStream(inputStream);
    File file2 = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "photo.png");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    IOUtils.copy(decryptedPhoto,outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
```

**Encryption**

```
public InputStream encryptInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception{
      KeyCipher keyCiper = new KeyCipher();
      String streamContent = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
      cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, keyCipher.getSecretSpecKey(), keyCipher.getIvParameterSpec());

     InputStream encryptedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(streamContent.getBytes("UTF-8")), DEFAULT).getBytes());
    return encryptedStream;
}
```

**Decryption**

```
public InputStream decryptInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception{
    KeyCipher keyCipher = new keyCipher();
    String streamContents = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode(streamContents, DEFAULT);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyCipher.getSecretSpecKey(), keyCipher.getIvParameterSpec());

    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    InputStream decryptedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedBytes);
    return decryptedStream;
```

Comment: What do you mean "see the photo"?  What exactly are you not seeing that you are expecting to see?

Comment: When i decrypt an encrypted photo i am unable to see the photo. So I encrypt a photo, then decrypt and am unable to view the original photo.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What exactly are you seeing?  Please be specific.

Comment: I see the file I created and in the android file viewer. But the photo is unable to be accessed, I am able to treat it as a txt in the file viewer to see contents of the file are there but it is simply a black photo(not original).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use char or toString() to handle encrypted streams. And also not utf-8 in any way. Its not text that you are streaming. Just stream the encrypted bytes and receive them as bytes.